# Comparing multiple dictionaries from JSON files?

Tags: python, json

Right now I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```json
"suggested":[{
    "city": "Berlin",
    "location": "Europe",
    "hotels": true,
    "restaurants": true,
    "rivers": false},
    {
        "city": "Andorra",
        "location": "Global",
        "hotels": false,
        "restaurants": true,
        "rivers": true
    }]
```

And I want to compare that JSON file, splitted in Dictionaries, with this "reference" JSON file:

```json
"master":[{
    "city": "",
    "location": "Europe",
    "hotels": true,
    "restaurants": false,
    "rivers": false
}]
```

My goal is to compare the values from the keys in `"master"` JSON with the ones of the inside dictionaries from the `"suggested"` JSON file, and return a print of how many matches they have. For instance:

```
"Berlin" matches with "Master" in (3) fields.
```

Right now I have my JSON file opened inside python, with a simple function:

```
def openJsonFile(file):
    with open (file) as json_data:
        workData = json.load(json_data)
        return(workData)
```

And this function to loop trough the opened files:

```
def compareJsonFiles(suggested, master):
    matches = 0
    for key in suggested.keys():
        value = suggested[key]
        if key not in master:
            print ("{0} doesn't have value in {1}".format(key, master))
        else:
            if master[key] == value:
                print("for key %s values match" % key)
                matches + 1
    print(matches)
```

But when I try to pass though the dictionaries, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

**UPDATE:**
I made this function, trying to pass each value from the json list as a separate dict.

```
def jsonToDict(file):
for lsdt in file:
    newListDic = file[lsdt]
    for key in newListDic.keys():
        value = newListDic[key]
        print(value)
```

It works giving me a dict. but it prompts:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

How can I loop through several dictionaries inside a JSON file and compare the key values with another JSON file?

P.S.: I've been searching for nearly two days without success, so I'd be glad if the first thing that happens to the post is not a "marked as duplicate flag".

Comment: You are apparently giving `compareJsonFiles()` a list instead of a dict, maybe you already called `.keys()`  ?

Comment: You wrote: "My goal is to compare the keys from the "master" JSON" and then, " "Berlin" matches with "Master" in (3) fields.". I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but I think that you want to compare not keys but the values (in this case 3 values which matches are "location": "Europe", "hotels": true, "rivers": false). Am I right?

Comment: @trojek yes, you're right. I've changed the body of the question to match that.

Comment: What you show as the content of your two input files isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @martineau according to this [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/?code=) is valid.

Comment: RD Department: All I can say is in that case, what's posted in your question must not actually be the contents of the files... Here's the JSON file format [specification](http://json.org), and as you should be able to plainly see, what you have in your question doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, the content your two input files isn't valid JSON format.

Here's modified versions of them to enable testing:

**`suggested.json`:**

```json
{
    "suggested": [
        {
            "city": "Berlin",
            "location": "Europe",
            "hotels": true,
            "restaurants": true,
            "rivers": false
        },
        {
            "city": "Andorra",
            "location": "Global",
            "hotels": false,
            "restaurants": true,
            "rivers": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**`master.json`:**

```json
{
    "master": [
        {
            "city": "",
            "location": "Europe",
            "hotels": true,
            "restaurants": false,
            "rivers": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's a modified version of your code that will process them the way you want:

```
import json


def openJsonFile(file):
    with open(file) as json_data:
        workData = json.load(json_data)
        return workData


def compareJsonFiles(suggested, master):
    master_dict = master['master'][0]  # Assumes only one object in the list.

    for suggestion in suggested['suggested']:
        print('checking suggestion:', suggestion)
        matches = 0
        for key, value in suggestion.items():
            if key not in master_dict:
                print ("  {0} doesn't have value in {1}".format(key, master_dict))
            else:
                if master_dict[key] == value:
                    print("  for key %r values match" % key)
                    matches += 1
        print('  there were {} matches'.format(matches))


suggested = openJsonFile('suggested.json')
master =  openJsonFile('master.json')

compareJsonFiles(suggested, master)
```

Here's the output it produces given the above two files:

```
checking suggestion: {'city': 'Berlin', 'location': 'Europe', 'hotels': True, 'restaurants': True, 'rivers': False}
  for key 'location' values match
  for key 'hotels' values match
  for key 'rivers' values match
  there were 3 matches
checking suggestion: {'city': 'Andorra', 'location': 'Global', 'hotels': False, 'restaurants': True, 'rivers': True}
  there were 0 matches
```

Answer (score 0):

You `master` node is list, not the dictionary. If you are sure that master always holds one entry only, pass it via

```
compareJsonFiles(suggested_data, master_data[0])
```

Comment: I see, but the "suggested" JSON has more than 10 dictionaries inside. 
`len(suggested)` returns "2" following the example I posted.
When I try to loop though it to extract one by one, the `def jsonToDict(file):
    for dt in len(file):
        file[dt]`
"an int cannot loop" propmts. I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Cerberus (not to be confused with Kerberos)
http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/usage.html#basic-usage

Everything you want, and more - general purpose JSON data validation and schems enforcement.

Comment: I'm going to check it @nigel222